# Return upper left value in a range if string is found - Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, join, filter, lookup

I have a Google sheet that has 'categories' listed in one cell. Then the data for that category is listed in multiple cells to the right of the category. For example see the image:

[example spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7PBym.png)

I need a formula that searches for a name in B1:C5 AND returns all values in A that correspond. For example, if my search term was "Elvis" it should return "Discus, Shotput".

Can anyone help?

I have tried Queries and a combination of Join + Filter

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
=join(", ",filter(scan(,A:A,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c))),(B:B=E1)+(C:C=E1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That worked very well. Now, what if I had another set of data similarly formatted in E:G? How would I search both sections and bring them together?

Comment: it would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data maybe and desired output so that it gives a clear picture of what is needed.

Comment: Here you go.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H14u6cDEIlnhFLQJFRsGUzUZ9EBEJSvhEV-t-Gwu0lE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The problem I'm running into is if the name isn't one of the sets of data, the whole thing errors out

Comment: Updated the formula in your sheet `Column L`. please do test it out.